# How to show negative value in sunburst chart using d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am stuck badly while trying to show negative values in sunburst chart. whenever I change the value in json file as negative the slice just gets hidden. I want the arc to show even if my arc has negative value.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="//d3js.org/d3.v7.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>


        chart = () => {
            var color = d3.scaleOrdinal()
                .range(['red', 'green', 'lightgreen']);

            const root = partition(data);

            root.each(d => d.current = d);

            const svg = d3.create("svg")
                .attr("viewBox", [0, 0, width, width])
                .style("font", "11px sans-serif")
            // .style('fill', 'black')

            console.log(svg)
            const g = svg.append("g")
                .attr("transform", `translate(${width / 2.5},${width / 2})`);


            const path = g.append("g")
                .selectAll("path")
                .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
                .join("path")
                .attr('fill', function (d, i, value) {
                    if (d.data.value > 10) {
                        return 'green'
                    } else if (d.data.value < 5) {
                        return 'red'
                    }
                    else if (d.data.value < 1) {
                        return 'lightgreen'
                    }


                    return color(i)
                })
                .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.current) ? (d.value ? 0.7 : 0.4) : 0)
                .attr("d", d => arc(d.current));


            path.filter(d => d.children)
                .style("cursor", "pointer")
                .on("click", clicked);
            path.append("title")
                .text(d => `${d.ancestors().map(d => d.data.name).reverse().join("-")} : ${format(d.value)} points`);
            path.append("info")
                .text(d => `${d.ancestors().map(d => d.data.size).reverse().join("/")}\n${format(d.value)}`);

            const label = g.append("g")
                .attr("pointer-events", "none")
                .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
                .style("user-select", "none")
                .selectAll("text")
                .data(root.descendants().slice(1))
                .join("text")
                .attr("dy", "0.35em")
                .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.current))
                .attr("transform", d => labelTransform(d.current))
                .text(d => d.data.name + '\n' + d.data.value);


            const parent = g.append("circle")
                .datum(root)
                .attr("r", radius)
                .attr("fill", "green")
                .attr("pointer-events", "all")
                .on("click", clicked);

            function clicked(event, p) {
                parent.datum(p.parent || root);

                root.each(d => d.target = {
                    x0: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x0 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
                    x1: Math.max(0, Math.min(1, (d.x1 - p.x0) / (p.x1 - p.x0))) * 2 * Math.PI,
                    y0: Math.max(0, d.y0 - p.depth),
                    y1: Math.max(0, d.y1 - p.depth)
                });

                const t = g.transition().duration(1050);

                // Transition the data on all arcs, even the ones that aren’t visible,
                // so that if this transition is interrupted, entering arcs will start
                // the next transition from the desired position.
                path.transition(t)
                    .tween("data", d => {
                        const i = d3.interpolate(d.current, d.target);
                        return t => d.current = i(t);
                    })
                    .filter(function (d) {
                        return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || arcVisible(d.target);
                    })
                    .attr("fill-opacity", d => arcVisible(d.target) ? (d.children ? 0.6 : 0.4) : 0)
                    .attrTween("d", d => () => arc(d.current));

                label.filter(function (d) {
                    return +this.getAttribute("fill-opacity") || labelVisible(d.target);
                }).transition(t)
                    .attr("fill-opacity", d => +labelVisible(d.target))
                    .attrTween("transform", d => () => labelTransform(d.current));
            }

            function arcVisible(d) {

                return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && d.x1 > d.x0;
            }

            function labelVisible(d) {
                return d.y1 <= 3 && d.y0 >= 1 && (d.y1 - d.y0) * (d.x1 - d.x0) > 0.03;
            }

            function labelTransform(d) {
                const x = (d.x0 + d.x1) / 2 * 180 / Math.PI;
                const y = (d.y0 + d.y1) / 2 * radius;
                return `rotate(${x - 90}) translate(${y},0) rotate(${x < 180 ? 0 : 180})`;
            }

            return svg.node();
        }
        adder = 10
        data = {
            "name": "KSE100",
            "children": [
                {
                    "name": "TEXTILE",
                    'value': 10,
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "COST",
                            "value": 4,
                            // 'points': 4

                        },
                        {
                            "name": "COOT",
                            "value": 3,
                            // 'points': 5


                        },
                        {
                            "name": "AHTM",
                            "value": "-3",
                            // 'points': 5

                        },

                    ]

                },
                {
                    "name": "OIL",
                    'value': 8,

                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "PSO",
                            "value": 2,
                            //'points': -20


                        },

                        {
                            "name": "BYCO",
                            "value": 6,
                            // 'points': -20


                        },
                        {
                            "name": "MPCL",
                            "value": 2,
                            //'points': 10


                        },

                    ]
                },
                /
            ]

        }


        partition = data => {
            const root = d3.hierarchy(data)
                .sum(d => d.value)
                .sort((a, b) => b.value - a.value);
            return d3.partition()
                .size([2 * Math.PI, root.height + 1])
                (root);
        }
        // color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.quantize(d3.interpolateRainbow, data.children.length + 1))


        format = d3.format(",d")
        width = 900
        radius = width / 10
        arc = d3.arc()
            .startAngle(d => d.x0)
            .endAngle(d => d.x1)
            .padAngle(d => Math.min((d.x1 - d.x0) / 2, 0.005))
            .padRadius(radius * 1.5)
            .innerRadius(d => d.y0 * radius)
            .outerRadius(d => Math.max(d.y0 * radius, d.y1 * radius - 1))


        const svg = d3.select('body').append(chart)

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

I  have been stuck in this since ages, I would be really thankfull if any of you can help me with this.

Comment: Use `Math.abs()` ?

Comment: I am sorry, I just copied this code from observable d3 website. I am not sure where to put it. can you please help me with that.

Comment: @FNasir Why the question of companies/sector is deleted?